# Ruby: Hexadecimal String to Binary String

Tags: ruby

I'm curious what's the best way to convert hexadecimal string to binary string in Ruby.

I.e.

```
def get_binary_string( hex_string )
  # what's the best way?
end

puts get_binary_string("2F")
output> "00101111"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could convert the hex `2F` to an integer (47), and then convert it back to a binary string (101111):

```
"2F".to_i(16).to_s(2)
# => "101111"
```

Comment: What if the hexadecimal string is very long and the integer conversion overflows?